# MAX9032 comparator to drive an LED for TX line

Tags: led, usb, uart, comparator, led-driver

I have got a MAX9032 dual comparator in one of the projects that I am working on and I have one spare comparator that I can use to drive an LED when the microcontroller is transferring the data to the PC that is connected to the USB. Would the following circuit work? This is designed to light up the LED when the TX line goes low(High means Idle state).

[image]

Comment: What is Tx ? state V and Z.

Comment: Sorry, Tx is the transmission line that connects to the USB. I was hoping to use that to know when the data is being sent.

Comment: Ok then USB2 levels 50 ohm source. meaning data upto 480Mb/s which uses NRZi encoding, meaning data is encoded by a polarity inversion.  So you want a comparator rated for this speed with very low capacitance. So your solution will not be effective.

Comment: Do you mean USB FS (Full-Speed, 12 Mbps) mode? Also, since you said "TX goes high means idle state", don't you mean D+ data line?

Comment: @AliChen Yeah, it is the D+ line